# Does iloc[ :, 1:2 ]. values and .iloc[ :, 1].values work differently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

If I slice a `pandas dataframe` with `dataset.iloc[:, 1:2].values`, it's giving me a `2 dimensional(matrix)` structured data where `dataset.iloc[:, 1].values` is giving me `1 dimensional` data. So, my doubt is `iloc[:,1:2]` & `iloc[:,1]` dont do the same thing ?

Here is the sample code:

```
    >>> df1 = df.iloc[:, 1:2].values
    >>> print(df1.shape,df1.ndim)
    (9578, 1) 2
    >>> df2 = df.iloc[:, 1].values
    >>> print(df2.shape,df2.ndim)
    (9578,) 1
    >>>
```

Comment: Since you're getting different results, it's pretty safe to say they don't do the same thing.

Comment: `.iloc[:,1]` returns series while `.iloc[:,1:2]` returns dataframe. It is the same as `df['A']` returns series while `df[['A']]` returns dataframe

Answer (score 4):

`df.iloc[:, 1:2]` returns a dataframe (matrix) whereas `df.iloc[:, 1]` returns a series (vector). A vector does not have column size. Try this if you want to keep the dataframe structure

```
df.iloc[:,[1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking slicing method you are using is called ['Selection by Position'](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-position). `iloc` is termed as integer based location.

When you use `df.iloc[:, 1:2]` resulting output would be a pandas DataFrame object:

```
>>> type(df.iloc[:, 1:2])
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

When you use `df.iloc[:, 1]` resulting output would be a pandas Series object:

```
>>> type(df.iloc[:, 1])
pandas.core.series.Series
```

Knowing the difference is critical because each object has different methods that may not work on other object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **iloc[:,1:2] & iloc[:,1]** these are not similar as one is giving Dataframe and other one is giving Serious as an output.

Using df.iloc[:,1:2] gives Dataframe and it give in 2-d as Dataframe is an 2-d data structure

```
type(df.iloc[:, 1:2])
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Using df.iloc[:,1] gives Series and Series is an 1-d labeled array

```
type(df.iloc[:, 1])
pandas.core.series.Series
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas `iloc()` is actually doing what you should expect in a Python context. Compare the following.

```py
>>> numbers = [0, 1, 2]
>>> numbers[1]
1
>>> numbers[1:2]
[1]
```

The former gives 0-dimensional data and the latter 1-dimensional data which is analogous to your example.